# PHP Segmentation fault using string

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I have the following line

```
$sql = "SELECT name, url, icon, hover, case_only, spacer FROM ma_menu_items WHERE hide = 0 AND deleted = 0 ORDER BY sort ASC";
```

If I run this the browser won't load and I get a Segmentation fault in the error logs. If I remove the `C` at the end it works, but if I remove the `ASC` it fails, there is different combinations that work and fail.

Please note there is no way for me to come up with a workable example of this as the application is too complicated for that (I've tried). What I am looking for is possible causes

Comment: Hi Jay, I believe the default sort is ASC. It is strange that the query fails if you leave it off. Is there a place in the following code that might be editing the SQL string? Try manually running the query prepended with the word EXPLAIN to get a better understanding of what is happening in the database and look between the string and where it's ran for places the strong might be getting edited.

Comment: It won't be possible to name a clear issue here. Obviously the string definition is valid and fine. My impression so far is that such segfaults occur due to broken dependency issues between php extensions getting loaded. Check your setup...

Comment: @Matthew The OP says the string definition itself fails, not the execution of the query later on.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not expecting a clear issue. I'm not sure what you mean by "Check your setup"

Comment: I mean check the php components. If the php module or process (don't know your setup) really segfaults, then it obviously has an issue with memory allocation. That is low level, has nothing to do directly with the script executed. So I suggest to check the versions of php and its extensions you have installed, upgrade or unify them. Use your systems software management utility for that. What that is depends on the distribution you use.

Comment: @arkascha Why would it only have low memory if it's written as above but if I remove a character then there is no low memory? I don't understand this

Comment: I did not refer to "low memory". A segmentation fault typically means that the process tries to access parts of the memory it has no permission to use.   Parts of the memory owned by _other_ processes. That certainly never should happen in this case, it shows that something is wrong with your setup on a very deep or basic level.

Comment: Sorry I misread memory allocation. I have tried it on a couple of servers and gotten the same result. I'm still not sure how a string would effect that depending on whats contained in the string. I would have thought it should happen no matter what the string has if that's the case